# affliate window csv to drupal node via batch api

Tags: php, drupal, csv, drupal-batch

i have an affliate window CSV which has nearly 1 lac rows, i want to save this as nodes, and i tried with batch API.

but still i am getting php timeout error ..please help

```
function MODULE_aw_batch(){  
  $operations = array();
  $csv = file_directory_path().'/aw/datafeed_134642.csv';
  $file = fopen($csv, 'r');
  while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
      $operations[] = array('MODULE_aw_op', array($data));
  }
  $batch = array(
    'title' => t('Generating feeds'), // Title to display while running.
    'operations' => $operations,
    'finished' => 'MODULE_aw_finished', // Last function to call.
    'init_message' => t('Importing...it may take 4-5 hours'),
    'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
    'error_message' => t('Import feeds has encountered an error.'),
  );
  batch_set($batch);
  batch_process('admin/content/node/overview');
}
```

## update (solved)

instead of reading whole csv file at a time, split the csv to read 5 lines per process

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on finding an answer to your own question. Please post it as an answer (it's fine to answer your own question), which makes it clear to other people that the question has an answer. You can also mark your own answer as accepted, if no other answer was more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution

**Batch declaration**

```
function MODULENAME_batch(){
    $operations[] = array('MODULENAME_op', array()); 
    $batch = array(
        'title' => t('Importing events'),
        'operations' => $operations,
        'finished' => 'MODULENAME_finished',
        'init_message' => t('MESSAGE HERE'),
        'progress_message' => 'MESSAGE HERE',
        'error_message' => t('MESSAGE HERE'),
    );
    batch_set($batch);
    batch_process('admin/content/node/overview');// redirect to this page
}

function MODULENAME_aw_op(&$context) {      
    if (!isset($context['sandbox']['offset'])) {
        $context['sandbox']['offset'] = 0;
        $context['sandbox']['records'] = 0;
    }

    $filename =file_directory_path().'/aw/datafeed_134642.csv'; // csv file

    $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');

    if ( $fp === FALSE ) {
    // Failed to open file
        watchdog('MODULENAME', 'Failed to open ' . $filename);
        $context['finished'] = TRUE;
        return;
    }

    $ret = fseek($fp, $context['sandbox']['offset']);

    if ( $ret != 0 ) {
    // Failed to seek
        watchdog('MODULENAME', 'Failed to seek to ' . $context['sandbox']['offset']);
        $context['finished'] = TRUE;
        return;
    }

    $limit = 5;  // Maximum number of rows to process at a time
    $done = FALSE;

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++ ) {
        $line = fgetcsv($fp);
        if ( $line === FALSE ) {
            $done = TRUE;
            // No more records to process
            break;
        }
        else {          
            $context['sandbox']['records']++;
            $context['sandbox']['offset'] = ftell($fp);
            $record = $context['sandbox']['records'];
            // Do something with the data

        }
    }

    $eof = feof($fp);

    if ( $eof )  {
        $context['success'] = TRUE;
    }
    $context['message'] = "processed " . $context['sandbox']['records'] . " records";

    $context['finished'] = ( $eof || $done ) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Drupal feeds module? It is pretty good for CSV importing.
http://drupal.org/project/feeds/

Comment: i wanted to process the some records , with feeds this is not possible , anyway found the solution :)

Comment: create an answer and share your solution